# Как на .NET прочитать XSD-файлы, если ссылки на другие файлы оформлены через <xs:any namespace=urn:....>?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

У меня есть 3 XSD-файла: ***main.xsd***, ***bah.xsd*** and ***body.xsd***.
Основной ***main.xsd*** содержит ссылки на 2 других XSD-файла таким вот образом:

```xml
<xs:any namespace="urn:......." processContents="strict"/>
```

Я читаю ***main.xsd***. Основная цель получить результат, который позволит построить дерево элементов из всех трех XSD-файлов -

```cs
private XmlSchema ReadAndCompileSchema()
{
    XmlSchema result = null;
    XmlSchemaSet xmlSchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(_thisAddIn.XsdSchemaFile))
    {
        result = XmlSchema.Read(reader, new ValidationEventHandler(
            (e, args) => throw new Exception("Can't read xml schema", args.Exception))
        );
        xmlSchemaSet.Add(result);
    }
    xmlSchemaSet.Compile();
    return result;
}
```

К сожалению, результат выполнения метода ReadAndCompileSchema() возвращает только элементы из ***main.xsd***, элементы же из ***bah.xsd*** и ***body.xsd*** - отсутствуют в result.
Тут не желательно сильно модифицировать .XSD-файлы.
Возможно, есть какой-то вариант изменить код на C#, чтобы можно было построить дерево элементов?

- ***main.xsd*** -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01">
<xs:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" schemaLocation="bah.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="BizData" type="BusinessData"/>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessApplicationHeader">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="StrictPayload">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:DRAFT6auth.093.001.01" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessData">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Hdr" type="BusinessApplicationHeader"/>
            <xs:element name="Pyld" type="StrictPayload"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

- ***bah.xsd*** -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
    <xs:element name="AppHdr" type="ApplicationHeader"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ApplicationHeader">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">ApplicationHeader</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation source="Definition" xml:lang="EN"></xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    ..........
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

- ***body.xsd*** -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:DRAFT6auth.093.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:DRAFT6auth.093.001.01" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
       .....................
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Мне кажется это похоже на ваш пример https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Просто закиньте в ваш schema set все три схемы, с остальным фреймворк разберётся:

```cs
var xmlSchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
foreach (var file in new [] { "main.xsd", "bah.xsd", "body.xsd" }) {
    using var reader = XmlReader.Create(file);
    xmlSchemaSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(reader, null));
}
xmlSchemaSet.Compile();
```